# Android - Whole data is not getting stored in Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I wanna know why my whole data is not getting stored in Firebase Database? Here is a Screenshot of of my data.

[image]

**Here is The Code**

```
private void sendMessage() {
        DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Message");
        String message = editTextMessage.getText().toString();
        if (message.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Text cannot be empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
           Messages chat = new Messages(user.getUid(), friendId, message, false);
           String chatID = db.push().getKey();
           db.child(chatID).setValue(chat);
           editTextMessage.setText("");
        }
    }
```

**My Model Class**

```
public class Messages {
    String senderId, receiverID, message;
    boolean isSeen;

    public Messages(){}

    public Messages(String senderId, String receiverID, String message, boolean isSeen) {
        this.senderId = senderId;
        this.receiverID = receiverID;
        this.message = message;
        this.isSeen = isSeen;
    }

    public boolean isSeen() {
        return isSeen;
    }

    public void setSeen(boolean seen) {
        isSeen = seen;
    }

    public String getSenderId() {
        return senderId;
    }

    public String getReceiverID() {
        return receiverID;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
```

As you can see I am storing 4 values in the `chat` object but it is only storing three.

Any Idea or Suggestion why this might be...

Comment: If the item `user.Uid();` is user firebase authentication id check that you're properly referring to the user id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost certainly the case that `friendId` is null.  Realtime Database won't store anything for null values.  We can't see where you are giving `friendId` a value, so you'll have to debug why this is.

Comment: Hi, I am actually facing the same problem again but this time value is not null and I have checked it in debugger. Why is this happening?